# How merge two select with different WHERE and special conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have table something like this:

```
date|status|value
```

date is date,
status is 1 for pending, 2 to confirmed
and value is value of order

I want to get 3 columns:

```
date|#status pending|#status pending+confirmed
```

example of data:

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| date       | status          | value           |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2015-11-17 |              1  |               89|
| 2015-11-16 |              1  |               6 |
| 2015-11-16 |              2  |              16 |
| 2015-11-16 |              2  |              26 |
| 2015-11-15 |              2  |              26 |
| 2015-11-14 |              2  |              24 |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

example of what I want:

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| date       | confirmed       |confirmed+pending|
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2015-11-17 |              0  |               1 |
| 2015-11-16 |              2  |               3 |
| 2015-11-15 |              1  |              1 |
| 2015-11-14 |              1  |              1 |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to do:

```
    SELECT array1.DATE
        ,array1.confirmed
        ,array2.total
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
            ,count(value) AS confirmed
        FROM Orders
        WHERE STATUS = '2'
        GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5
        ) AS array1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
            ,count(value) AS total
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5
        ) AS array2
```

But I get 4 results per date with repeated confirmed value and different total transactions.

If I try separated, I can get both correct informations:

will list only sum of confirmed orders of last 5 days:

```
SELECT array1.DATE
    ,array1.confirmed
    ,array2.total
FROM (
    SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
        ,count(valor) AS confirmed
    FROM Orders
    WHERE STATUS = '2'
    GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5;
    )
```

will list sum of all orders of last 5 days:

```
SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
    ,count(valor) AS total
FROM Orders
GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5
```

I observed at least one big problem:

Sometimes we will have one day with a lot of not confirmed orders and zero confirmed, so probably inner join will fail.

Comment: Your second query has some sintaxys error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN`, To get the expected output,you have given.

```
SELECT `date`,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN `status`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Confirmed,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN `status`=1 OR `status`=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Confirmed_Pending
    FROM
    table_name
    GROUP BY DATE(`date`) DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `ON` clause in your `INNER JOIN`. Or, since in your case the column you join on is the same on both sides, you can use `USING`:

```sql
SELECT array1.DATE
    ,array1.confirmed
    ,array2.total
FROM (
    SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
        ,count(value) AS confirmed
    FROM Orders
    WHERE STATUS = '2'
    GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5
    ) AS array1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DATE (DATE) AS DATE
        ,count(value) AS total
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY DATE (DATE) DESC limit 5
    ) AS array2
USING (DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach could be to use a `case` expression to evaluate whether the status is something you'd like to count, and apply the `count` function to that:

```
SELECT   DATE (`date`) AS `date`,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS `confirmed`,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN (1, 2) THEN 1 END) AS `pending and confirmed`,
FROM     orders
GROUP BY DATE (`date`) DESC
```